# Decorators code result difference in cmd versus sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext

I am trying to learn decorators by following the 'python decorators in 12 steps'. http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

I tried replicating one of the In one of the code examples:

```
def outer(some_func):
  def inner():
    print ("before some_func")
    ret = some_func()
    return ret + 1
  return inner      

def foo():
    return 1

def main():
    decorated = outer(foo)
    decorated()
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

This results in :

```
before some_func
```

In the example under Decorators!

```
>>> def outer(some_func):
...     def inner():
...         print ("before some_func")
...         ret = some_func() # 1
...         return ret + 1
...     return inner
>>> def foo():
...     return 1
>>> decorated = outer(foo) # 2
>>> decorated()
```

Returns:

```
before some_func
2
```

The main difference is that in the example, they are using Python running directly from cmd and I am using the Sublime text with python build as well as using a main() function. In my mind, I feel like these are doing the exact same thing. Is there something different between running code in the cmd versus with sublime that I am not getting?

Answer (score 1):

The interactive Python interpreter automatically prints the results of a line if it is not assigned to a variable. This is useful for debugging. For example, if you call foo(), it will automatically print 1. The call below would not result in any extra prints in the interactive interpreter.

```
>>> result = decorated()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So does this mean that foo() is also returning 2 as well in my first example but we cannot see it?

Comment: I also tried assigning foo() to a variable: bar=foo() and calling bar() but I get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: when you say bar = foo(), you are setting it to the result of calling foo. This is why you get the error. You could say bar = foo and then call bar(), because you are assign the function foo to bar and not the result of foo. calling foo() will always return the result 1. You get the result 2 from calling decorated() because the function inner adds one to the result of foo.